# Porque "PHP e MYSQL"

Tags: php

comecei a aprender PHP a pouquíssimo tempo e tenho pesquisado bastante sobre o assunto. Estou com uma dúvida que pode parecer meio óbvia e "boba" pra maioria de vocês. A minha dúvida é, porque a maioria dos livros/cursos que vejo na internet "sempre" estão com o nome "PHP e MySQL" sendo que cursos e livro das outras linguagens não tem esse acréscimo de "e MySQL".

PHP é tão dependente de DB assim, ou tem outra explicação pra isso ?

Comment: PHP é a linguagem de programação, mysql é o banco de dados. Eles costumam andar juntos devido a maioria das aplicações precisar de persistir dados, ou seja, guarda-los de forma organizada. Dá pra fazer isso com outros meios, mas sem duvida o banco de dados é a melhor escolha. Mas não é impossivel fazer uma aplicação apenas com a linguagem.

Comment: Porque a maioria gosta de ensinar receita de bolo ao invés de ensinar a programar de verdade. Cursos mais sérios costuma ter mais foco e ensina a base, ensina a pessoa a pensar por conta própria, ser criativo, saber como resolver qualquer tipo de problema, entender os fundamentos para aplicar a ferramenta certa na hora certa. Mas a maioria prefere ser popular e isto significa dar coisas prontas pra pessoa copiar. Agrada mais e "forma" péssimos "profissionais". Receitas de bolo precisam ser completos. Especialmente em PHP a moda é dar as receitas e não ensinar nada.

Comment: Pela facilidade de se encontrar servidores na internet que tem suporte a essas tecnologia,por isso se encontra muito material focando neles 2. onde uma linguagem de programação , um banco de dados são peças importantes para fazer um formulário por exemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente, o PHP é uma linguagem de programação e o MySQL é um SGDB (banco de dados). Ambos são distintos e independentes um do outro.

O fato de encontrar muitos materiais abordando os dois é por serem os mais populares. Simplesmente isso.

## Pacotes

O que você mais encontrará é materiais com o conjunto LAMP ou WAMP:

```
L->Linux
A->Apache
M->MySQL
P->PHP

W->Windows
A->Apache
M->MySQL
P->PHP
```

Outro conjunto popular é o XAMP

```
X->Windows, Linux, OS-X (mac)
A->Apache
M->MySQL
P->PHP
```

Por quê o conjunto LAMP é tão popular?

Simplesmente porque não há custos com licenciamentos, são open-source e podem ser usados comercialmente.

Mas então você pergunta por que há pouco ou quase nenhum material para PGSQL (postgre)? Afinal é também um banco de dados open source.

Nesse ponto estamos falando de capitalismo.

## Capitalismo, marketing

Numa analogia, você tem um bar onde oferece 2 cervejas. Uma é popular e amplamente aceita a outra é tão boa quanto porém, pouco conhecida. Para atrair clientes para o seu bar você não vai colocar um cartaz na porta com a marca desconhecida de cerveja. Os clientes passariam direto e iriam para outro bar onde tem um cartaz com a cerveja popular normalmente acompanhada da imagem de uma pessoa famosa no momento.

Ou seja, um livro com título "php e mysql" vai vender muito mais que um livro "php postgre".

Os servidores de hospedagem também dão preferência aos conjuntos mais populares e de baixo custo, no caso o LAMP.

## MariaDB

obs: Atualmente encontrará muitos pacotes incentivando o MariaDB e desincentivando o uso do MySQL. Isso é um assunto de longa discussão e polêmico por isso é inviável comentar aqui. Mas basicamente o MariaDB é o MySQL. Nasceu após uma discórdia entre o criador do MySQL e a Oracle.

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado cara. De quebra eu entendi porque desses nomes  XAMP, WAMP, LAMP.

Answer (score 4):

Não que o PHP seja "tão" dependente assim de banco de dados, apenas que você não consegue resolver facilmente tantos problemas só com linguagens de programação.

Para citar um exemplo que aparece muito aqui no StackOverflow: como mandar email a partir de formulários. Isso é uma coisa que você consegue fazer só com uma linguagem de programação, não precisa de banco de dados. Porém fazer um sistema de "padaria" já fica bem mais complicado de fazer sem banco de dados. Não é impossível, mas tampouco é fácil, ou desejável. Isso porque bancos de dados implementam o [modelo ACID](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID), que ajuda muito quando você não tem controle de requisições paralelas, concorrentes. E que de outra forma você teria de implementar na mão, na ausência de bancos de dados.

Basicamente os cursos estão vendendo "linguagem de programação **e** banco de dados" de uma maneira explícita, já que a combinação de PHP e MySQL é bem comum (ver [LAMP](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP)). Os livros que não explicitamente incluem um banco provavelmente estão explicando só a linguagem mesmo, enquanto que os cursos provavelmente ensinam banco, apenas não colocando no nome do curso isso.